# std::vector and std::list memory layout

Tags: c++, list, memory, vector, stl

We know that std::vector gives a continuous memory layout, while std::list gives a linked memory layout, and my question is what is the memory layout of std::vector< std::list >? Does it contain contents of std::list or it just contains several pointers to the lists?

Comment: It's the same as any other `std::vector<T>` (unless `T=bool`): it contains an array of `T`. In this case, it is an array of `std::list`.

Comment: @nneonneo: It almost smells like OP is wondering if vector would contain list's elements if list itself is an element of a vector.

Comment: Well, in that case the answer is obviously NO. `std::vector` doesn't care what `T` is as long as it is copyable. (In principle, you *could* design a container that had specializations for carrying other containers...)

Comment: @nneonneo: Exactly. You should put those two comments as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is true that `std::list` keeps its elements in separately allocated memory locations connected with each other as a linked list, a small area of memory is needed for the header structure of the list itself. It is this structure that gets allocated when you create an instance of `std::list<T>`.

A vector of `std::list<T>` consists of these "header" items for the individual linked lists, allocated in a contiguous region of memory:

[image: Vector of Lists]

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as any other `std::vector<T>` (unless `T=bool`): it contains an array of `T`. In this case, it is an array of `std::list`. A `std::list` object is basically a bookkeeping structure for the list of objects it "contains"; the actual elements are in separately-allocated chunks outside of this structure (and therefore outside the memory block managed by `std::vector<std::list<T> >`).

Note that `std::vector` doesn't care what `T` is as long as it is copyable. In principle, you could design a container that had specializations for carrying other containers, but this isn't how `std::vector` works.